# WinForm C# Efficient Search of DataGridView (unbound)

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a C# winForm that uses the dataGridGrid and I'm receiving about 20 msgs per/sec  and I have approx 1000 rows...is there any "fast lookup" methods and/or design pattern that will allow me to locate specific rows without iterating through dataGridView.Rows collection? This seems to be a VERY inefficient approach but I can't seem to find anything else other than dataGridView.Rows.Remove() which I "think" is a loop, am I correct? Can someone please help me out?

Thanks in advance,

-DA

Comment: What are you trying to do with the lookup? Remove a row, add a new item, get some value, something else?

Comment: so you're trying to remove rows.?

Comment: Basically my grid is reflecting "real-time" messages that I have to render to the grid in the form of(Add,Update,Delete) and these msgs are coming in by the milliseconds in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

you could probably use some LINQ to find the row, since it is unbound. I don't know what you're matching against, but hopefully this could help:

```
var x = (from DataGridViewRow r in dataGridGrid.Rows 
         where r.Cells[SomeCellIndex_OrName].Value == "Some Value"
         select r).FirstOrDefault();

if (x != null ) {

  //Do Something to x
  // x is your row
  // x == null when not found
}
```

Comment: thanks for the LINQ suggestion, but isn't' that just a sugar coated forLoop?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly your question, you want to find specific rows in your DataGridView and delete them. 
Assuming you are using DataGridView try to bind it's DataSource to a BindingSource and then you could find(last added) row like this:

```
    BindingSource.Position = BindingSource.Find(string PropertyName, object key);
```

To remove selected row, save your position to a variable and then:

```
    DataGridView.Rows.RemoveAt(your variable);
```

Hope that helps